# How would I compare the two column in Sequelize Postgres Database using node.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

In my Postgres DB, there are two columns, one is for `email` and another one is for storing the `roles`, the roles are `customer` and `engineer`. Here, some emails are containing the `customer` as a role and some are the `engineer` as a role in DB. When I retrieve the data from DB, I need to verify that the email is matching to that particular role(customer/engineer). How to write the condition using nodejs.

```
id | role     | email
---+----------+------------------------
1  | engineer | testemail01@gmail.com
---+----------+------------------------
2  | customer | testemail02@gmail.com
---+----------+------------------------
3  | engineer | testemail03@gmail.com
---------------------------------------
```

while retrieving I need to compare the `testemail01@gmail.com` is `engineer` or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to make sure there is a record with specified email and role then you can use `count` method and simple `where` condition like this:

```js
const roleCount = await Model.count({
  where: {
    email: 'testemail01@gmail.com',
    role: 'engineer'
  }
})
const isEngineer = roleCount > 0;
```